# Error occurs while trying to print variables in fortran

Tags: fortran

I use window 10. I use Xstart compiler. 
The exact problem is to write type declarations to declare them as real variables.
Temperature, Pressure, Volume Type declarations are needed to declare these three as real variables.
I should print it and show the result.
Below is my program. To run the program I write pgf90 ww.f90.
Since a.out is the command that shows the latest calculation result, use a.out to print the result.

```
program disting
implicit none
REAL :: Temperature, Pressure, Volume print *
end program disting
```

When I run this program, I get this error.

```
error at or near identifier print (ww.f90: 3)
0 informs, 0 warnings, 1 severes, 0 fatal for disting.
```

Why is this not printing?

Comment: Please do really take the [tour] to find how to use this site. And do also remove your older question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61194517/when-i-run-the-program-only-black-space-appears else it will attract downvotes. Avoid stuff like "Come an tell me" in titles.

Comment: The error message comes from the print statement not being on a separate line.  Of course, the print statement `print *` doesn't have any variable to print but that isn't erroneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
program disting
implicit none
REAL :: Temperature, Pressure, Volume 
print *, Temperature, Pressure, Volume
end program disting
```

If you explicitly print out your variables it works fine. The * is not a wildcard, it simply tells the computer to output the data that follows in a format compatible with the type of items contained in the following comma delimited list. You were missing the list to print out.

I tested this here: https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-fortran-online/

Comment: Thank you. I was really troubled by looking at the textbook and asking me to solve the problem. No matter how much I tried Google Ring, I couldn't find the answer.